# Creating an id with src attribute from a function or variable, how?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a common javascript function to obtain source image location based on the PM2.5 value. The following code do not work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Finding the aqiicon.</p>
    <p id="#aqiicono"></p>

    <script>
      var aqiicon = "";
      var pm25o = 12.0;
      // aqiicon = pm25toicon(pm25o);
      $("#aqiicono").attr("src", pm25toicon(pm25o));
    </script>

    <script>
      function pm25toicon(pm25) {
        if (pm25 < 12.1) {
          return "'img/aqi1.png'";
        } else if (pm25 < 35.5) {
          return "'img/aqi2.png'";
        } else if (pm25 < 55.5) {
          return "'img/aqi3.png'";
        } else if (pm25 < 150.5) {
          return "'img/aqi4.png'";
        } else if (pm25 < 250.5) {
          return "'img/aqi5.png'";
        } else {
          return "'img/aqi6.png'";
        }
      }
      // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = pm25toicon(300);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Function pm25toicon receiving PM2.5 value and return appropriate location of icon, I then tried to assign source attribute to an id by the statement:

```
$('#aqiicono').attr('src', pm25toicon(pm25o));
```

Appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in your scripts, here is a suggestion:

- **First**, you should call your function when the page is properly loaded with Jquery
- **Second** you shouldn't put any return "'" ortherwise, your img will look like :
- **Third** you're trying to load an image inside a `<p>` edit it to `img`
  Here is the code

  Finding the aqiicon.

  ```
  <script>
    var aqiicon = "";
    var pm25o = 12.0;

    function pm25toicon(pm25) {
      if (pm25 < 12.1) {
        return "img/aqi1.png";
      } else if (pm25 < 35.5) {
        return "img/aqi2.png";
      } else if (pm25 < 55.5) {
        return "img/aqi3.png";
      } else if (pm25 < 150.5) {
        return "img/aqi4.png";
      } else if (pm25 < 250.5) {
        return "img/aqi5.png";
      } else {
        return "img/aqi6.png";
      }
    }

    // Replace src when document is loaded
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#aqiicono").attr("src", pm25toicon(pm25o));
    });
  </script>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Updated your code a little bit.

1. changed `<p id="#aqiicono"></p>` to `<img id="aqiicono" />`
2. Moved fcn declaration up before usage

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Finding the aqiicon.</p>
<img id="aqiicono" />


<script>
function pm25toicon(pm25) {
if (pm25 < 12.1)
{return "'img/aqi1.png'";}
else if (pm25 < 35.5)
{return "'img/aqi2.png'";}
else if (pm25 < 55.5)
{return "'img/aqi3.png'";}
else if (pm25 < 150.5)
{return "'img/aqi4.png'";}
else if (pm25 < 250.5)
{return "'img/aqi5.png'";}
else
{return "'img/aqi6.png'";}
} 

var aqiicon = ''
var pm25o = 12.0;
// aqiicon = pm25toicon(pm25o);
$('#aqiicono').attr('src', pm25toicon(pm25o));
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it working now. The working code is now:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again. Here is the working code suggested by you two:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Finding the aqiicon.</p>
<img id="aqiicono" />


<script>
function pm25toicon(pm25) {
if (pm25 < 12.1)
{return 'img/aqi1.png';}
else if (pm25 < 35.5)
{return 'img/aqi2.png';}
else if (pm25 < 55.5)
{return 'img/aqi3.png';}
else if (pm25 < 150.5)
{return 'img/aqi4.png';}
else if (pm25 < 250.5)
{return 'img/aqi5.png';}
else
{return 'img/aqi6.png';}
} 

$('#aqiicono').attr('src', pm25toicon(pm25o));
</script>


</body>
</html>
```